# exporting jar with eclipse not saving changes?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm editing the source project for a plugin called socialAuth. After making some changes I saved and tried to export the project to a jar. It completed without errors but a few warnings. However when taking a look at the class files I noticed my changes were not there! I checked the box for source files when exporting, so I'm not sure why the changes aren't going through. The project does not have a manifest but a pom file. I'm not quite sure what info I should provide, so let me know if you need it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild of the project. That should refresh the .class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select following option during export:

`Export Generated class files and resources`

Cheers !!